# Make not producing output

Tags: c, makefile, output

```
all: 1.c 2.c 3.c

1.c:
  gcc 1.c -o 1
2.c:
  gcc 2.c -o 2
3.c:
  gcc 3.c -o 3
```

So when I type "make", why is no file produced (it just tells me "make" is up to date.) and what am I doing wrong?!

Note that 1, 2, and 3 are not my actual file names.

Comment: This is a very basic problem which is handled in every tutorial at the very beginning.

Comment: @AleksandarMakragić: What do you mean "how do I create all"?

Comment: Please watch Make tutorial. As Olaf said before, this is most basic question.

Comment: @Olaf: Does this very basic problem happen to be something you know the answer to?

Comment: Ok first, what are you trying to accomplish here? Do you want to create 3 separate executable files for 3 different programs, or do you want to merge them into one?

Comment: 3 separate files for 3 different programs.

Comment: Ok, check my answer. If you have any further questions feel free to ask. But you should really do some tutorial on Make since it is very important tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
all: 1 2 3

1: 1.c
    gcc 1.c -o 1
2: 2.c
    gcc 2.c -o 2
3: 3.c
    gcc 3.c -o 3
```

How does make know what to compile? He checks last modified time of dependencies! And if dependency file has modified after the target file only then he's doing the work!

He checks `1 2 3` and their dependencies. Dependency for `1` is `1.c`. And now, if `1.c` is modified after `1` only then will he do `gcc 1.c -o 1`. Since in your case `1` doesn't even exist, Make will create this file for you.

> Target: all -> Dependencies: 1 2 3
>
> Target: 1 -> Dependency: 1.c
>
> Target: 2 -> Dependency: 2.c
>
> Target: 3 -> Dependency: 3.c

And now he checks, what was last modified, `1` or `1.c`? I don't even have `1`, so I'll create target file `1` using `gcc 1.c -o 1` etc.

Next time, if you have your `1` file and you modified your `1.c` he will see that file `1` was created before `1.c` was last modified and so he will do again `gcc 1.c -o 1`.

Answer (score 0):

With `1.c:` you are defining the rule to construct the object "1.c", you need to say you are constructing object "1"

```
1: 1.c
    gcc 1.c -o 1
2: 2.c
    gcc 2.c -o 2
3: 3.c
    gcc 3.c -o 3
```

Comment: And also: all: 1 2 3?

Comment: Objects should add `.o` suffix or that left to an implicit rule. Also that will not just generate the object, but an excecutable.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this..

```
# Makefile template
CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -I. 
OBJ=1.o 2.o 3.o 
DEPS= library1.h library2.h library3.h 
all: X
    @echo "Finish."
X: $(OBJ)
    @echo "Building the application core.."
    $(CC) -o x $(OBJ) $(CFLAGS)

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    @echo "Building objects.."
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
clean: 
    @echo "Cleaning up.."
    rm -f $(OBJ) x
```

***Source:***
http://www.cs.colby.edu/maxwell/courses/tutorials/maketutor/